# Python Type Annotations Union

Tags: types, annotations, union

This code is causes errors by type checking with mypy:

from typing import Union, Literal

x: Union[int, Literal['stop']] = 3

y: Union[int, Literal['stop']] = 0

y += x

This code solves the problem:

from typing import Union, Literal

x: Union[int, Literal['stop']] = 3

y: Union[int, Literal['stop']] = 0

if isinstance(y, int) and isinstance(x, int):

```
y += x
```

I think there may be a better more elegant solution for this?